# Lottery winning chances python

Tags: python, probability

I'm trying to create a lottery simulation to see what are the chances of winning.
I begin very simply : my program should run the lottery x times, and then to find the probability of winning should divide the numbers wins by the number of loss.
My problem is how to count wins and store them ?
The code for now is:

```
from random import randint

for i in range (1,1001):
    a = randint(1,1000)
    print (a)
    if a == 1:
```

from there i don't know what to do ???

what to do to store 1 (the winning ticket) each time it occur in order to estimate the chances of wining ?

Comment: Increment a `winner` variable whenever it wins. Then just divide that by the number of repetitions you did.

Comment: You don't divide by the number of losses. But if you need that, just subtract the number of winners from the total number of tries.

Answer (score 1):

Store the counts in a variable.

```
from random import randint

winCount = 0

for i in range (1,1001):
    a = randint(1,1000)
    print (a)
    if a == 1:
        winCount += 1

winProportion = winCount / 1000
```